# Step vs Make a step vs Take a step

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

- Who is older than 18, please step forward
- Who is older than 18, please make a step forward
- Who is older than 18, please take a step forward

Is there any difference between **step**, **take a step**, and **make a step**?

Which is more natural?

Comment: That's not how native speakers issue such "polite requests". *Anyone who is over 18, please step forward* would be natural. In a more authoritarian (military?) context, *...[please] **take** a step forward* would be far more likely. To ***make** a step forward* would be idiomatically unusual, except maybe in the context of a fearful "tip-toe" towards potential danger (or @Adam's *advance almost imperceptibly towards one's goal*).

Comment: BTW, we have said **whoever** in that construction for a few centuries now.  **who** is not grammatical there.

Answer (score 9):

**"Make a step forward"** is a slightly awkward use of an idiom meaning "make incremental progress towards a goal."

*"We have a long way to go before we have eradicated homelessness, but every year we make small steps forward."*

**"Step forward"** or **"Take a step forward"** mean move one leg out, and step onto it.

*"When you hear your name called, step forward, and you will be presented with a golden avocado."*

---

Also:
***"Who is 18**, step forward."* is still awkward due to the first clause.  I would expect to hear either ***"Anyone** who is 18, step forward."*  or ***"Everyone** who is 18, step forward."*

Comment: I'll add that to my question

Comment: Of course, outside of the army parade drill context, ***step forward*** implies each participant will take *multiple* steps (up onto a stage, perhaps). And with rows of theatre seats / bleachers / whatever you could still be invited to step forward even though it's physically impossible for you to take ***a*** step forward (until you've inched sideways to the aisle at the end of your row).

Answer (score 0):

### 'make a step' forward seems fine in cases like

1) when there is some **foot session involving instructions** like, "turn left and  make/take a step forward(backward)". "now take a step backward and jump"

2) **signifying progress towards some ascertained goal**, like "for every opportunity I get, i make/take a step forward in the direction(to something)

While , 'step forward' is generally fine in all other scenarios